# Multiple Python Scripts in Docker

Tags: python, docker

This is quite a basic question but I haven't been able to get an answer from researching on Google, although I think its more due to my lack of understanding, than the answer not being out there.

I am getting to grips with Docker and have a python Flask Admin script and a postgres db both in two separate containers but under on docker-compose file. I would like another python script to run at the same time which will be scraping a website. I have the file all set up but how do I include it in the same Docker-Compose or DockerFile?

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - PG_PASSWORD=XXXXX
  dev:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
      - ./run.sh:/code/run.sh
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
       - db
```

Comment: Post your docker-compose.yaml

Comment: Just posted. Thanks for help

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a db and one python script set up on docker. The python script is a Flask Admin interface for the db. I have another standalone (script2) python script that scrapes websites to be entered into the db. I don't know how to get script2 in the docker package to be set up with the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what to write depends on your directory configuration, but you basically want

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - PG_PASSWORD=XXXXX
  dev:
    build: <path-to-dev>
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
      - ./run.sh:/code/run.sh
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  scraper:
    build: <path-to-scraper>
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The two paths might be the same. You might push an image and then reference that instead of building it on the fly. You might do the same business of just mounting the code directory instead of building it into the image (but don't do that for actual deployment).